# Selective flattening of JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, hierarchical-data, flatten

I'm extracting data from an API which returns non-standardised jsons, meaning that I have to write a custom function to parse each data stream as the JSON has a different structure of nested dictionaries and lists. The output I desire is a flattened list containing all of the relevant endpoint items. I've written functions for a few of these but am trying to create something more generalisable.

An example JSON would be of the form:

```
JSON = {
    'metadata' : {
        'meta_param' : 'meta_value',
    },
    'contents' : [
        { 
            'content' : [
                {
                    'attributes' : {
                        'series_name' : 'series_1a',
                    },
                    'data' : {
                        'index' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        'values' : [12, 84, 38, 3, 92, 67]
                    },
                },
                {
                    'attributes' : {
                        'series_name' : 'series_2a',
                    },
                    'data' : {
                        'index' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        'values' : [42, 73, 48, 20, 19, 61]
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            'content' : [
                {
                    'attributes' : {
                        'series_name' : 'series_1b',
                    },
                    'data' : {
                        'index' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        'values' : [13, 85, 39, 4, 93, 68]
                    },
                },
                {
                    'attributes' : {
                        'series_name' : 'series_2b',
                    },
                    'data' : {
                        'index' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        'values' : [43, 74, 49, 21, 20, 62]
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

And I'd write a custom function like this to convert it into a flat list

```
flatlist = []

for contents in JSON['contents']:
    for content in contents['content']:
        flatlist.append(content['data'])

flatlist -> 
[{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [12, 84, 38, 3, 92, 67]},
 {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [42, 73, 48, 20, 19, 61]},
 {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [13, 85, 39, 4, 93, 68]},
 {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [43, 74, 49, 21, 20, 62]}]
```

I'm trying to create a function which accepts a JSON of nested dictionaries and lists, as well as a 'routemap' of how to access specific items within it, and then returns a flat list of the specified items.

A routemap and its usage for the previous example would look like:

```
JSON_route = [
    'contents',
    'content',
    'data',
]

flatlist = json_to_flatlist(JSON, JSON_route)

flatlist -> 
[{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [12, 84, 38, 3, 92, 67]},
 {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [42, 73, 48, 20, 19, 61]},
 {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [13, 85, 39, 4, 93, 68]},
 {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [43, 74, 49, 21, 20, 62]}]
```

My key issue is that I'm not sure how to programmatically convert the JSON_route list into the nested for loops needed to extract the data.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have trouble parsing the JSON, or is this just another question that's not really about JSON at all?

Comment: maybe do a recursive function to identify the keys first and their hierarchy, and then go through them one by one?

Comment: @ HeapOverflow No problem in parsing the JSON, the issue is creating a generalisable function to parse different data streams which have a different nested structure of dictionaries and lists.

Comment: Oh wait, that's not even JSON. So yeah, yet another "JSON question" that has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @hmghaly I know the hierarchy in advance and can specify it within a JSON_route similar to the one in OP. I'm looking for a way to convert the list structure of JSON_routes to the for loops needed to iterate over the lists within the JSON

Comment: @HeapOverflow I'm looking to parse data thats using the javascript object notation, how is that not a JSON question?

Comment: Because you're already past the JSON stage. You only have a Python data structure question.

Comment: It's a question on how to use Python to parse a specific data structure which is in a JSON format. Non-standard refers to the fact that each data stream has a different hierarchy to reach the data.

Comment: Can you edit the title/contents of your post to better reflect what the question actually is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def json_to_flatlist(obj, route):
    if len(route) == 0:
        yield obj
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            yield from json_to_flatlist(item, route)
    else:
        yield from json_to_flatlist(obj[route[0]], route[1:])

JSON_route = [
    'contents',
    'content',
    'data',
]

result = list(json_to_flatlist(JSON, JSON_route))
print(result)
```

Result (newlines added for clarity):

```
[
{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [12, 84, 38, 3, 92, 67]}, 
{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [42, 73, 48, 20, 19, 61]}, 
{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [13, 85, 39, 4, 93, 68]}, 
{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'values': [43, 74, 49, 21, 20, 62]}
]
```